# Perl Mongo find object Id

Tags: perl, mongodb

You would think it is a simple thing. I have a list of object id's that are in my collection. I would like to get a single record based on an object id. Have Googled, but nothing helpful.

So I have object id: 5106c7703abc120a04070b34

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new;
my $db = $client->get_database( 'myDatabase' );

my $id_find = $db->get_collection('mycollection')->find({},{_id =>      MongoDB::OID->new(value => "5106c7703abc120a04070b34")});

print Dumper $id_find;
```

This prints:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_skip' => 0,
                 '_ns' => 'MindCrowd_test.Users',
                 '_grrrr' => 0,
                 'partial' => 0,
                 '_query' => {},
                 '_tailable' => 0,
                 '_client' => bless( {
                                       'w' => 1,
                                       'query_timeout' => 30000,
                                       'find_master' => 0,
                                       '_servers' => {},
                                       'sasl' => 0,
                                       'wtimeout' => 1000,
                                       'j' => 0,
                                       'timeout' => 20000,
                                       'sasl_mechanism' => 'GSSAPI',
                                       'auto_connect' => 1,
                                       'auto_reconnect' => 1,
                                       'db_name' => 'admin',
                                       'ssl' => 0,
                                       'ts' => 0,
                                       'inflate_dbrefs' => 1,
                                       'port' => 27017,
                                       'host' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
                                       'dt_type' => 'DateTime',
                                       'max_bson_size' => 16777216
                                     }, 'MongoDB::MongoClient' ),
                 '_limit' => 0,
                 'slave_okay' => 0,
                 '_request_id' => 0,
                 'immortal' => 0,
                 'started_iterating' => 0
               }, 'MongoDB::Cursor' );
```

I have tried different verions of the above find. All of them fail to compile:

```
$mongo->my_db->my_collection(find({_id => "ObjectId(4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000"}));

$mongo->my_db->my_collection(
```

find({ _id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "4d2a0fae9e0a3b4b32f70000")})
);

NONE of them work. How do I find (findone) a single record using the object id??

Answer (score 7):

the find methods returns a Cursor object for iterating through. If you only want one record use the find_one method which returns a value.

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new;
my $db = $client->get_database( 'myDatabase' );

my $id_find = $db->get_collection('mycollection')->find_one({_id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "5106c7703abc120a04070b34")});

print Dumper $id_find;
```

Comment: That too returns the same wrong answer. When I connect to mongo it self I can see that id via a find().pretty(). When I do the find_one in PERL all I get back is:{
          '_id' => bless( {
                          'value' => '51030e053739330d6caa7007'
                        }, 'MongoDB::OID' )
        };

Comment: Fixed, didn't notice youd also got the parameter s the wrong way round.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Not sure how I ended up with the parameters that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this has changed. MongoDB::OID has been deprecated, replaced by BSON::OID, which does not have a method that allows you to pass in the 24-byte hex string that you have. Here's what you have to do these days:

```
my $id = "5c7463277fc2198b64654feb";
my $oid = BSON::OID->new(oid => pack('H24', $id));
my $result = $db->get_collection('mycollection')->find_id($oid);
```

`pack` creates a 12-byte binary sequence from the 24-bytes of hexadecimal data you have in $id. This is what BSON::OID is expecting, and then the perl driver constructs the correct filter for you in the background.